# Bitbake autotools

Tags: yocto, autotools, bitbake, autogen

I have set up a recipe of mine to use autotools to make my project. I recently decided to run bitbake with the verbose output turned on. I noticed nowhere in my build or compilation does `autogen.sh` get called. It goes straight to my `configure.ac`.

Why is this? I thought `autogen.sh` was required. Is there a way to make it use `autogen.sh`?

Comment: I could believe it going straight to `configure`.  Is that what you mean?  `configure.ac` is not an executable file.

Comment: In any case, I'm not sure about bitbake's specific requirements, but `autogen.sh` is not a natural part of an Autotools build system.  It is a convention on top of the Autotools, with some degree of popularity, but plenty of Autotools build systems do not provide such a script.

Comment: I am seeing that autogen.sh is not necessary. My only issue now is with the boost library.

Comment: in my case ./configure takes some parameters. how should I pass them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OE-Core's autotools.bbclass is setup to run autoreconf, libtoolize and the other tools needed itself without using the autogen.sh since they can vary a lot in quality. Your software will have configure regenerated, it just won't use the helper script.